# What is the most secure method for web session handling for multiple domain?

Tags: session-management, single-sign-on

Based on the current standing of web security, what is the most secure / recommended method for web session handling: session cookies, cookie jars, web tokens, or anything else?

The requirement is to develop one single sign on authentication / session handling for multiple web applications running on different domain / server.